# Eliminar entrada array que se ubica en otro array PHP

Tags: php, array

tengo un array:

```
$lista = array(1,2,3,4,5.5);
```

y tengo otro array:

```
$comprado = array(3,5.5);
```

lo que deseo es mostrar solo los elementos del array $lista que no se encuentren en el segundo array $comprado.

al final la idea es que quede asi:

```
$lista = array(1,2,4)
```

ya que 3 y 5.5 se encuentran en $comprado;

de antemano gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pides lo obtienes fácilmente usando [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php) de este modo:

```
$lista = array(1,2,3,4,5.5);
$comprado = array(3,5.5);

$lista = array_diff($lista, $comprado);

// regeneramos números de indice del array con sort()
sort($lista);

print_r($lista);
```

Te da como resultado un array con estos datos:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
)
```